# Is it possible to receive the displayed rows (and order ?) of a React Material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using React to render a  component which I chose to use for its filtering capability that I found nowhere else. By default, let's say it displays 10 rows of my data.

As I filter the table, the rows displayed will be different, maybe 10, maybe less in function of my filtering.

The simple question is : Can I recover the rowData of the rows that are displayed ?

Thank you !
David

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.

First create a reference to material table component

`<MaterialTable
tableRef={this.tableRef}
.
.
/>`

So you will have your data in: this.tableRef.current.state.data

Also, you can do console.log(this.tableRef) and check others info are there

Best Regards